# Blender Python: Cancel Operator without closing props_dialog

Tags: python, blender

I'm developing [a Blender Add-on](https://github.com/hugoaboud/BlenderDMX), and the default "Invoke -> Execute -> Close" flow of Blender Operators is not the most user-friendly one for my case. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

I have a `layout_props_dialog`:

[image: layout_props_dialog add_fixture]

When the user clicks 'OK', I need to validate some fields before allowing the operator to run. However, returning `CANCELLED` from the `execute` method closes the dialog, which is a bad UX pattern.

I'm aware of Modals, however this doesn't seem to be the usual case for it, since the action (adding a fixture) happens only once, after the form is correctly filled.

```py
# DMX_Fixture_AddEdit contains prop declarations and the draw method.

class DMX_OT_Fixture_Add(DMX_Fixture_AddEdit, Operator):
    bl_label = "DMX: Add Fixture"
    bl_idname = "dmx.add_fixture"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        dmx = scene.dmx
        if (self.name in bpy.data.collections):
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        if (not len(self.profile)):
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "No GDTF Profile selected.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        if (not len(self.mode)):
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "No DMX Mode selected.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        for i in range(self.units):
            dmx.addFixture(self.name+" "+str(i+1), self.profile, self.universe, self.address, self.mode, list(self.gel_color))
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.name = "Fixture "+str(len(context.scene.dmx.fixtures)+1)
        self.units = 1
        DMX_Fixture_AddEdit.profile_list_items = []
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```

So, in short, I need to cancel the execute method without closing the `layout_prop_dialog`.
I've also tried with `RUNNING_MODAL`, `PASS_THROUGH` and `INTERFACE`. All presented the same behaviour.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Remove `{'CANCELLED'}` return from the `if` statements, and set all your properties displayed in the `layout_prop_dialog` to default values instead. Could help the way you are doing `self.report` and just reassigning all your variables, so the user should fill them again.

```
class DMX_OT_Fixture_Add(DMX_Fixture_AddEdit, Operator):
bl_label = "DMX: Add Fixture"
bl_idname = "dmx.add_fixture"
bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

def execute(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    dmx = scene.dmx
    if (self.name in bpy.data.collections):
        #set the properties you use in the UI to default values
        pass
    if (not len(self.profile)):
        self.report({'ERROR'}, "No GDTF Profile selected.")
        #set the properties you use in the UI to default values
    if (not len(self.mode)):
        self.report({'ERROR'}, "No DMX Mode selected.")
        #set the properties you use in the UI to default values
    for i in range(self.units):
        dmx.addFixture(self.name+" "+str(i+1), self.profile, self.universe, self.address, self.mode, list(self.gel_color))
    return {'FINISHED'}

def invoke(self, context, event):
    self.name = "Fixture "+str(len(context.scene.dmx.fixtures)+1)
    self.units = 1
    DMX_Fixture_AddEdit.profile_list_items = []
    wm = context.window_manager
    return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)
```